# Passing html element value to composeWithTracker in React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

This Meteor code uses React. When user fills in an input box with id `myVal`, click a button. The input box value gets sent to the server via a method, the server updates the collection `vehicles`.
It then needs to take that input from user and use that as query to collection.findOne in `myfile.jsx`. It failed to pass the user input `myVal` from html input element.
How can it be done? Thanks

```
// -------------------- myfile.jsx -------------------
const renderWhenData = ( cars ) => {
  if ( cars ) {
    return <span>{ cars.description }</span>;
  }
};

const Info = ( { cars } ) => (
  <p>{ renderWhenData( cars ) }</p>
);

  const composer = (props, onData) => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('vehicles');
  if (subscription.ready()) {

    let myVal = document.getElementById('myVal').value;
    console.log(myVal);  // <------------------ nothing is printed out
    const cars = Vehicles.findOne({name: myVal});
    onData(null, {cars});
  }
};

const Container = composeWithTracker(composer)(Info);
ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('react-info'));

// --------------------- events.js -----------------------
document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const myVal = document.getElementById('myVal').value;
  Meteor.call('startInfo', myVal);  // <---------- updates server collection
});
```

```html
<!--main.html-->
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <form action="submit">
    <input type="text" id="myVal">
    <div id="react-info"></div>
  </form>
  <footer>
    <button id="startButton">START</button>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks alright. What is the error that comes in the console?

Comment: @vijayst nothing is printed out, please see code change for `console.log(myVal);`

Comment: initial value of textbox is empty. So, it works fine. If you want some value there, initialize the textbox in html with some value.

Comment: @vijayst There is a value in the input box on the page. why isn't getting injected in the variable `myVal`?

Comment: If you typed in after the page loaded, it won't work...

Comment: @vijayst well, that is the whole reason of my question, How can I get it to work so that after the page is loaded and the button is clicked "please see my edited questiont"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122974/discussion-between-vijayst-and-fred-j).

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit academic. There are better ways to handle this in React. But, since you are using Meteor, this can be done with some Tracker operations.

First define a tracker dependency:

```
export const textboxDep = new Tracker.Dependency;
```

Whenever the textbox value changes, trigger the changed event.

```
textboxDep.changed();
```

Within the composer, use

```
textboxDep.depend();
```

If the composer is written well, when the tracker dependency is invalidated, the whole functional container component runs again. And you should see the value of the textbox there.

Right now, when the value of the textbox is changed, since it is not reactive, the container does not re-render itself.

Comment: How can I apply this concept so that it invoked when the button is clicked and waits till the method updates the collection, then shows the found value. Not when the textbox changes.

Comment: It only runs once on start up. There must be a way this React Komposer package does things.